# combining different threading approaches to a windows forms application

Tags: c++, winforms, multithreading, openmp

I'm developing a windows form application that aims at performing real time image manipulation. User interface is a key element and I want to use multithreading to perform image processing tasks separate from the UI thread. Not only this, but due to the intesity of the calculations I wish to perform the image processing on multiple threads.

One way I have managed to do this is by using the ThreadStart delegate to do the processing on multiple threads. This works quite well but I am explicitly creating each thread. Another approach I have looked at is using openMP to perform processing tasks on multiple threads. OpenMP seems to be a much simpler approach since it automatically assigns the processing to all available threads. This would be paricularly useful where the program is run on different computers with different numbers of cores on each. However I find that the user responsiveness is lacking with the openMP approach and I have come to the conclusion that this is due to calculations being done on the UI thread as well.

I hence tried to combine the two approaches, I start a new thread using threadstart from which I call a function that performs the image processing using openMP to parallelize a for loop. However when I do this the program does not use all of the threads available to it (it seems to only use 2 or 3 out of 8).

Hence my questions are the following: Would it be bad practice to try and do the multithreading in these two different ways? Is there a way to successfully implement the combination of approaches such that it does the image processing on all available threads but leaves the UI thread to handle user input? Or perhaps there is a simpler implementation using only one of the above approaches? I realise that I could probably dynamically create threads using threadstart but this seems like a more complicated approach then if I could use openMP instead.

Here is some pseudocode showing what I want to do (note: ProcessedData and ImageData are unsigned char arrays of pixel data):

```
//this sets up a new thread when called for in the form
public: static void ThreadProc()
{
    ProcessedData=compute(ImageData); //this is the image processing, there are other variable as well as ImageData
};

//this computes the processed image when the user moves a label/node
private: void labelnode_MouseMove( Object^ /*sender*/, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e ) {
    //if not being moved or left mouse button not used, exit    
    if (!bMoving || e->Button != System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Left)    
    {       
        return; 
    };
    Thread^ oThread = gcnew Thread( gcnew ThreadStart( &Form1::ThreadProc ) );
    oThread->Start(); //launch new thread to do calculations for image processing
};
```

The compute function contains the following parallel loop:

```
#define CHUNKSIZE 1 
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, CHUNKSIZE)
    for (i=0;i<numberofrows;i++)
    {
        //Process all of the pixels in the given row putting results in the processed data array.
    };
};
```

UPDATE: Actually it turns out that the debugging tools were preventing the full performance of the application. Running the exe externally works as it should. However, now I have a memory leak which causes a crash after the process has been repeated enough times. I'm sure there was no memory leak before I parallelised with openMP so I'm wondering if there is some residual memory left from the continuous opening and closing of threads. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is right: it's a recommended pattern to keep the main thread for UI responsiveness and start a separate thread for compute-intensive job, using OpenMP (or any other parallel framework) to process this job in parallel.

Why it does not use all HW threads/cores this way is a separate question. It might be due to load imbalance, or some synchronization issues, or significant serial portions of computation, or the amount of work being insufficient for all threads all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The openMP loop is setup to dynamically send rows of pixels in an image to be processed. It works perfectly without threadstart using all 8 available threads so I don't think there is load imbalance or synchronisation issues etc. but when I use threadstart to try and separate it from the UI thread the parrallelised for loop seems to only run on 1 thread. I have tried to manually set the num_threads but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Perhaps a piece of (pseudo)code for what the main thread is doing and what the compute thread is doing and how OpenMP is used would be helpful.

Comment: It seems correct to me, I do not see any obvious issues. Seems it makes sense to use debugger or performance analyzer to understand how many threads are there, what those threads do, etc.